# "Would like" vs. "should like" vs. "may like"

Tags: modal-verbs

What are the differences between 1, 2 and 3?

> 1. I would like you, too.
> 2. I should like you, too.
> 3. I may like you, too.

Is 1 in agreement with politeness?

Comment: Do you actually mean "*I would like you to*" as in "I would like you to clean your room?" As written, I expect your sentence to continue like, "*I would like you, too, but you smell bad.*" (so I don't like you after all). To put my question directly: are you trying to say you would/should/may like *the person* or you would/should/may like *something they do*?

Answer (score 2):

**Would** indicates consequence of an imagined event; it shows intent

**Should** implies a conviction in the speaker. One could also say I "ought to" instead of saying should.

**May** implies permission from another person. Although in this case, I think you really mean to use the word **might** to indicate possibility instead of permission.

To answer your last question, politeness is a cultural and personal perspective, but I think that it is polite to use the first one.